# How to use input parameters in sp_executesql from other stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have stored procedure `sp_Example` with input parameters `@param1 @param2` etc. Inside `sp_Example` stored procedure I'm using `dynamic query` with returning results by calling `sp_executesql`. Once `sp_executesql` executed, It can't see parameters from `sp_Example` and I got following error: `Must declare the scalar variable @param2`

This is example of how my `sp_Example` looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Example
@param1 INT,
@param2 NVARCHAR(20) = ''
AS
BEGIN
   IF (@param1 = 1)
      BEGIN
         -- There doesn't matter how select looks like so I pass dots
         SELECT @cols += .... + ','
                FROM   (SELECT  ....
                        FROM    ....
                        WHERE   ....
                        ) a                         
                SET @cols   = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)
                SET @sql    = 'SELECT * FROM 
                (
                    SELECT  ....                        
                    FROM    ....
                    WHERE   FI.test = @param2 -- Here I'm trying to get input parameter
                                              -- @param2 from sp_Example
                ) x 
                PIVOT
                (
                    MIN (Val)
                    FOR NamePiv IN (' + @cols + ') 
                ) p'

                EXEC Sp_executesql @sql  -- This one is IMPORTANT row
                                         -- When this executed I got error:
                                         -- That must declare scalar variable @param2

      END
...
END
```

Any ideas how to solve It?

Comment: Supposed to work with both MySQL and MS SQL Server?

Comment: It's based on SQL server.

Comment: You tried using `N'` where you are setting `@sql` ? I think when using `Sp_executesql` its almost a requirement if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, if you meant ` SET @sql    = N'SELECT * FROM ` this not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `@Param2` to `sp_ExecuteSQL` as:
Check correct syntax on [sp_ExecuteSQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sql, N'@Param2 NVARCHAR(20)', @Param2
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but `@param1` also used in the same `WHERE clause`. After I did that now I got the same error just about `@param1`: `Must declare the scalar variable @param1` I've tried:
`EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@param2 NVARCHAR(20)', @param2, N'@param1 INT', @param1`

Comment: that is not correct syntax, check the linked article for correct syntax.

`sp_executesql @sql, N'@param2 NVARCHAR(20), @param1 INT', @param2, @param1`

Comment: Thank you, but this conflicting with `WHERE clause` In my where clause are lines: 
`WHERE 
FF.Id = EE.Id AND
... AND
FF.UserId = @param1  AND
(FF.UserName = @param2 OR @param2 = '')`

Comment: I got following error:
`(Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ') FF.UserName = @param2 OR @param2 = ' to datatype INT`

Comment: I'm trying to execute: `EXEC sp_Example @param1 = 1, @param2 = ''`

Comment: `PRINT` your `@sql` and check the output to see the generated statement, that can help you resolve the issues.

`PRINT (@sql)`

Comment: I got following error: `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')
    ) x 
    PIVOT
    (
     MIN (Val1)
     FOR NamePiv IN (converted values as columns...) 
    ) p'`.

Comment: Maybe that because I use `[ ]`, I mean (FF.[Test] = @param2 or @param2 = '')

Comment: If I use `PRINT(@sql)` It sucessfully returning code

Comment: Ahh but It returning: ` (FF.[Test] = @param2 or @param2 = ')` with 1 `'` I don't know why, so that and conflicting.

Comment: you need to escape that with two single quotes: `''''` instead of `''`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70287/discussion-between-vishal-gajjar-and-infinity).